# Creating App in paypal sandbox

Tags: api, paypal

I am creating an app in paypal sandbox account under apps and credentials option.
but the "Create App" button is disabled. I do not know why.[button is gray and un clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xbff.jpg)

Comment: Hi Qasim, you just need to confirm Your PayPal account email you used to log in @ that developer.paypal.com site; it uses the same paypal.com login email and pw

Comment: @GeekNinja I have confirmed the email, but it is not working.

Comment: Could be you're hitting a country issue as REST is only available in U.S. Although I thought you would at least be able to use REST in Sandbox Mode. Can you verify if your email is in confirmed in your paypal account? Profile/Settings / Email, update - check

Comment: @GeekNinja yes I have confirmed my email, I am in pakistan. But if I was able to create account then should be able to create app also. Or they should display a message related to this.

Comment: go here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus, what message do you get?

Comment: I found this, appears pakistan is not supported https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/country-codes/#paypal-account-payments, sounds like a country matter. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create sandbox account for US merchant and see if the create APP button is enabled? If yes, then at least it will narrow down the problem with PayPal probably not supporting some country instead of a bug on their website.